# Java LinkedList iterator and Thread Safety for game with RenderThread and UpdateThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, linked-list, thread-safety

Simply I have a shared java LinkedList in an Android app that has 2 Threads, a render thread and an update thread. Both threads run continously and keep on iterating over the shared LinkedList. Sometimes the update thread has to remove an object from the LinkedList. How do I code the program such to keep multithreaded performance but allowing this to happen. I keep receiving a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException from the render thread because I am guessing the object is being removed while I am trying to render it.

Please note, I use iterators in my code...

```
public void run()
{
  if(Thread.currentThread() == renderThread)
  {
    while(true)
    {
      for(Iterator<GameObject> it = objects.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
      {
         it.next().render();
      }
    }
  }
  if(Thread.currentThread() == updateThread)
  {
    while(true)
    {
      for(Iterator<GameObject> it = objects.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
      {
         GameObject o = it.next();

         it.next().update();

         if(o.shouldBeRemoved())
             it.remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One possible solution is to catch the Exception and just ignore it, but I feel that is the cheaters way out since exceptions should be used for exceptional circumstances, not flow.

Comment: simply lock(`synchronized`) the `GameObject`(not the whole list) by each thread is using it.

Comment: You should be creating a lock on the List, because that's where you might get in to trouble. i.e. Removing an element from list, when it is being Iterated. Also, I'd suggest you to use Synchronized for locking the list object rather than the thread comparison as done above.

Comment: Or you would use a thread-safe list too.

Comment: Doesn't synchronizing the list basically make this a single threaded application though?

Comment: No, it does not. It ensures that only one thread can access it at a time.

Comment: I can see many different defects in your code: One multi-purpose-method for two different tasks; non-proper synchronization of shared state; wrong usage of iterators; both threads running in busy loops... Why do you actually have two different threads for update and rendering? Use just one thread that does both things in sequence. That's maybe not the most performant solution, but it saves you from lots of headache!

Comment: @isnot2bad : If I want the objects to continue in a standard "speed" and sacrifice the animation, what is the better way? I feel that if the render loop starts taking a long time, it won't effect my update thread which means that my objects will continue to "move" at the right speed. (even if it isn't drawn as often) What is the solution to that with only one thread?

Also, I have tried wrapping "synchronized" around my LinkedList and Object instance with no luck.

Comment: @Matthew Have you already experienced performance problems? Have you used a profiler to find bottlenecks? If you want to separate update from rendering by using threads, synchronizing the objects list is only one thing. Because both threads will access the objects too, their state must be synchronized too. If you don't do this in a clever way (e.g. by working with thread-confined snapshots), you will not gain much performance but instead have a complex, error-prone system. Of course, it is doable, but it requires some higher experience in concurrency I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [modifying your list structurally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) in **update thread** while, at the same time, the **render thread** has created an **Iterator** and is having fun iterating your objects. You're getting `ConcurrentModificationException` as a punishment for not handling synchronization issues.

Try searching for any example with **synchronized block/method** and **wait()/notify()**.

**UPD:** Ok, here is a simple modification of your code, which does not throw an exception. This is not a good example of List synchronization, you do not gain much performance (update and render operations are still in different threads, but performed sequentially), and there are few things to consider - if any other thread tries to modify your List, you will still get a concurrent exception.

In your launcher class define two threads:

```
private Thread t1, t2;
```

Code that lauches threads (e.g., `inside public static void main(..)`):

```
final List<GameObject> list = initList();//some initialization
t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myMultipurposeMethod(list);
        }
    });

 t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myMultipurposeMethod(list);
        }
    });
 t1.start();
 t2.start();
```

Now a simplified version of your **GameObject** class. Pay attention to synchronized blocks:

```
class GameObject {

    private int id;
    private static int count = 0;
    private boolean shouldDelete = false;
    private Object monitor = new Object();//will be used to lock critical section

    public GameObject() {
        id = ++count;
    }


    public void update(Thread thread) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            shouldDelete = Math.random() < 0.5;//just a simple randomization
            System.out.println(thread.getName() + " updates GameObject. should be removed =" + shouldBeRemoved());
        }
    }

    public boolean shouldBeRemoved() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            return shouldDelete;
        }
    }

    public void render(Thread thread) {
        System.out.println(thread.getName() + " renders GameObject " + id);
    }
}
```

And finally, your multipurpose method:

```
public void myMultipurposeMethod(List<GameObject> ls) {
    synchronized (ls) {
        if (Thread.currentThread().equals(t1)) {
            while (true) {                    
                for (Iterator<GameObject> i = ls.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                    i.next().render(Thread.currentThread());
                    ls.notify();
                }
                try {
                    ls.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (Thread.currentThread().equals(t2)) {
            while (true) {
                for (Iterator<GameObject> i = ls.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                    GameObject o = i.next();
                    o.update(Thread.currentThread());
                    if (o.shouldBeRemoved()) {
                        i.remove();
                        System.out.println("game object with id=" + o.id + " marked as garbage and was removed");
                    }
                }
                ls.notify();

                try {
                    ls.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTract();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will give you **an illusion** of parallel execution and prevent your Exception from happening, if you follow the requirements given in the preamble. However, in order to achieve a real performance gains, you would be better off following  @isnot2bad advices given in the comments to OP.

Comment: This code is for a game that "continuously" runs. The run method is called from 2 different threads and then each go into their respected loops. (I'll worry about getting out of the threads when it comes time to terminate the game)

Comment: Drew thanks for the code and help. It appears from your explanation though that this is a multithreaded app that basically acts like a single threaded app because of the wait and notify. Is that correct? If so, it appears it would be best to simply use a single thread?

Comment: Not exactly. This is still a multithreaded app, and renders/updates happen **off the main thread**. But if you wish to follow the strategy you proposed in OP, you will end up with these two threads working one after the other. I can not propose you the best solution, but I guess, it would be nice if: in the **update** thread you would choose, if your object should be rendered or removed, and in **render** thread you would either render or remove the object. Then you will modify your list structurally only in one thread, and you can schedule threads with different priorities.